# Bootstrap 4 Input Controls - Change auto complete background color on the selected items?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm really stuck with finding where I can override the bootstrap control for auto-complete background color of a form-control to something other than white as it does not look good for my dark theme.

Input Control - Background color goes white after entering a input value using auto complete:

[image]

This is no good, needs to the gray colour

I was also getting a similar behavior for a select (dropdown box), after selecting an item from the list, the background was going white as you see in the image below:

[image]

[image]

I did find a solutoon for the select dropdown list which is to overrride Bootstrap with custom CSS, see below:

```
select.form-control:focus::-ms-value {
color: #ffffff; /* Set text to white for selected item */
background-color: transparent; /* remove background color for selected item*/
}
```

I am still however looking for a solution in changing the default background color for autocomplete from white to the gray color of my theme, thx

Answer (score 1):

The background on autocomplete in chrome is inherited from Webkit. To address this field try to use:

```
input:-webkit-autofill { 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
}
input:-webkit-autofill:focus { 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
}
```

You can change white for background color and green for your desired font color.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on Chrome, this is the rule that applies on text inputs when autocompleting:

```
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
    background-color: rgb(232, 240, 254) !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

You could try changing that to your own styles and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, just tried that now but unfortunately didn't fix it. I guess it would need to be a CSS component that will override the bootstrap CSS. Like looking for needle in a haystack, spent many hours on this so far. Could it be i need to reference the css to the select.form.control in some way? thanks

Comment: What I'd recommend is inspecting the element when they styles you don't want are applied, see which rules are being applied at that moment and just target those with your own CSS